# Cannot connect to local openfire server from C#

Tags: c#, xmpp, openfire

I've setup a openfire server in a vm, and its accessible from internet(I've done the port-forwarding to point to the ip of the vm).

I can chat using spark so openfire is working perfectly.

Now I am trying to connect my c# app to the server and I am getting error.

Code :

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var client = new XmppClient("192.168.0.109", "pbc92", "12345"))
            {
                try
                {
                    client.Connect();
                    client.StatusChanged += client_StatusChanged;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
                }

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
    }

private void client_StatusChanged(object sender, S22.Xmpp.Im.StatusEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(e.Jid.ToString());
}
```

The error :

[image: Error Message]

Comment: try to add the host to your jabberId pbc92@hostname

Comment: tried that.my Windows 2003 server name is winserv. but pbc92@winserv or pbc92@winserv.com doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: You might want to add a tag for whatever XMPP lib you are using.

Comment: Hey, what library were youtrying to use here? S22 or the Sharp.XMPP fork?

Answer (score 0):

Try with Sharp.Xmpp, it is a fork of the currently frozen S22.Xmpp.

https://github.com/pgstath/Sharp.Xmpp